# ios Constraints Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints, uistoryboard

I have a scrollView with the following constraints:

[image]

I am adding a View with the following constraints to it. Basically CameraView and MyPicImageView are supposed to fill the whole View, FlipCamBtn is supposed to be in the Lower Right hand corner, Button in the Lower Left Hand Corner, Save Image Btn in the Top Right corner and Capture in the Bottom Center of the screen.:

[image]

I have the following code which adds this View to the scrollView.

```
mainScrollView.hidden = false
    var CameraView : CameraViewController = CameraViewController(nibName : "CameraViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(CameraView)
    self.mainScrollView.addSubview(CameraView.view)
    CameraView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

The problem is that my View appears too large and the buttons are off the screen.

Comment: Try switching around the constraints first <-> second that have put the `superview` as the first item e.g. `trailing = Camera View.trailing`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand, can you rephrase?

Comment: Select a constraint, then from the constraints pane (right-hand side) you can see it lists `First Item`, `Relation`, and `Second Item`. For any that have `Superview` as the first item, click the dropdown `Superview.xxxxx`, and at the bottom, choose `Reverse First and Second Item`.

Comment: Do I do this only for the view or for the scrollview as well?

Comment: Ideally you want the inside view (e.g. button inside a containing view) to be the first view, and the container to be the second view. Switch any constraints that don't adhere to this principle.

Comment: I made these changes, however it didn't effect the result

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not add constraints between `self.mainScrollView` and `CameraViewController.view`, the view will be added as is in its superview.

This mean the size of the xib will be the size of the view at runtime (except if some subviews constraints force the parent view to resize). Right now the xib you are seeing is not showing the results of the constraints you have added to it because there is this orange arrow at the top right of the views list in your screenshot. First try to fix the warning by running `Update frames`.

If this does not solve anything you'll have to add constraints between `CameraViewController.view` and `self.mainScrollView` programmatically.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Comment: Which constraints should I add programmatically to bound the view to the size of the screen? Can you please provide a short code example of how to do that?

Comment: I guess `self.mainScrollView` is a `UIScrollView` ? Then you need to set `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` to `0` and the `CameraViewController.view`'s height and width equal to those of the `self.mainScrollView`.

Comment: Yes it is a UIScrollView.

Comment: I tried this `  CameraView.view.frame.height = self.mainScrollView.frame.height
        CameraView.view.frame.width = self.mainScrollView.frame.width` but it says they are get only properties

Comment: Don't manipulate the frames manually if you use autolayout. Refer to the link in my response to see how to add layout contraints programmatically right after `self.mainScrollView.addSubview(CameraView.view)`

Comment: So something like this? NSLayoutConstraint(item: CameraView.view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainScrollVIew, attribute:.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant:0.0).active = true ?

Comment: yes, and same for to, bottom, left, right, width ;)

Comment: bottom left right width of the scrollView? and do I have to somehow apply these constraints or is that one line enough?

Comment: no you're right, you have to create them (your line above) and add them: `self.mainScrollView.addConstraint()`. `UIScrollView` needs 6 constraints with its content. If you have trouble have a look here: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/

Comment: also what do I need the to,bottom,left,right constraints for?